# normpdf() of MATLAB in R

Tags: r, matlab

[image: z]what is the best substitute for `normpdf()` function of MATLAB in R. Where, normpdf(x) of MATLAB, returns the probability density function (pdf) of the standard normal distribution, evaluated at the values in x.

I tried the `dnorm()` function in R, however, it is giving me an error which is -

```
Error in dnorm(z) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Note: the matrix which I am using is `z` that belongs to `dgeMatrix class` with the dimensions (645x7).

Can someone enlighten what's going wrong over here. I appreciate the help,
Many thanks.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: `dnorm` takes a vector of quantiles as `x`.  Please show your `z`.  If it is vector of quantiles with class `dgeMatrix`, try `dnorm(as.matrix(z))`

Comment: I have edited my post with the snapshot of z matrix.

Comment: Ok, I think my solution would work if you are thinking that `x` should be the only variable.  There are also `mu` and `sigma` arguments in `dnorm`

Answer (score 1):

The `dgeMatrix` can be convert to regular `matrix` with `as.matrix` which is just a vector of values with `dim` attributes

```
dnorm(as.matrix(z))
```

Or directly convert to `vector` with `as.vector`

```
dnorm(as.vector(z))
```

#### data

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(24)
z <- as(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 20), "dgCMatrix") + 1
> class(z)
[1] "dgeMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
```